# definition of a function that replaces the head of Project Gutenberg texts with RegEx

Tags: regex, function, header

I'd like to write a function that removes the head of Project Gutenberg texts using RegEx.

So far I did the following (not as a function), that worked well:
(dracula is a textstring of the Dracula novel from Projekt Gutenberg)

```
pattern = r'START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK (.)+?\*\*\*'

draculalist = re.split(pattern, dracula, maxsplit=1)
draculalist.pop(0)
dracula = ''.join(draculalist)
print dracula[:100]
```

-> worked well, as well as:

```
headend = re.search(pattern, dracula).end()
dracula = dracula[headend:]
```

Then I tried to write a function:

```
def head_removal(text):
    """Entfernung der Meta-Daten im Kopf der Projekt Gutenberg Texte"""
    headend = re.search(pattern, text).end()
    text = text[headend:]
```

The problem is that when I use the function with a certain text like

```
head_removal(dracula)
```

it will not change the string 'dracula' as it is immutable of course but gives me the object 'text' which has the dracula-text without the header. 
So I tried it with the other code that splits the string into a list and than joins it again:

```
pattern = r'START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK (.)+?\*\*\*'

def head_removal2(texts):
    """Entfernung der Meta-Daten im Kopf der Projekt Gutenberg Texte"""
    liste = re.split(pattern, texts, maxsplit=1)
    liste.pop(0)
    texts = ''.join(liste)
```

Doesn't work either for
    head_removal(dracula)
    print dracula[:100]

Any idea how to write that function?

Answer (score 0):

Python is "[pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)" which means you can't "assign" a value to the original reference inside your function - you'll have to return the result from the function and assign it back to the original string.

```
def modify_test(dracula):
    pattern = r'START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK (.)+?\*\*\*'
    draculalist = re.split(pattern, dracula, maxsplit=1)
    draculalist.pop(0)
    dracula = ''.join(draculalist)
    return dracula[:100]

# call it and re-assign:
dracula = modify_test(dracula)
```